# Automating setting node positions in \foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there a way to automate setting nodes at the intervals of the `\foreach` marks so they can be referred to, for drawing the braces; instead of defining their locations manually.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{ci}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\incx}{.88}
\draw [thick,-] (0,0) -- +(0:8.8) node [pos=.146](a){a} node [ pos=.296](b){b} node [pos=.44](c){c} node [pos=.586](d){d} node [pos=.876](e){e} node [pos=.73](f){f};
\foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \aff using int(\x*1)]in {1,...,6}{\draw [black, very thick] (\incx*1.46*\x,.2) -- +(-90:.4);}
\draw [blue, thick, decorate, decoration={brace,amplitude=.16cm,mirror}] (b.center|-0,-.4) -- (d.center|-0,-.4) node [blue!80!black, midway, xshift=0cm, yshift=-.5cm] {middle};
\draw [blue, thick, decorate, decoration={brace,amplitude=.16cm}] (a.center|-0,.4) -- (b.center|-0,.4) node [blue!80!black, midway, xshift=0cm, yshift=.5cm] {series};
\draw [blue, thick, decorate, decoration={brace,amplitude=.16cm,mirror}] (e.center|-0,.4) -- (f.center|-0,.4) node [blue!80!black, midway, xshift=0cm, yshift=.5cm] {draw};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
\foreach[count=\j] \i in {a,b,...,f}
    \draw[-|] (\j,0) -- ++(1,0)node[below]{\i}coordinate(\i);
```

to draw lines and name the nodes using `\foreach`.

[image]

#### MWE

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\tikzset{brce/.style={blue, thick, decorate, decoration={brace,amplitude=.16cm},}}
\tikzset{brcetxt/.style={blue!80!black, midway, xshift=0cm,}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach[count=\j] \i in {a,b,...,f}
    \draw[-|] (\j,0) -- ++(1,0)node[below]{\i}coordinate(\i);
\draw (f)--++(1,0);

\draw [brce,decoration=mirror] (b|-0,-.4) -- (d|-0,-.4) node [brcetxt,yshift=-.5cm] {middle};
\draw [brce] (a|-0,.2) -- (b|-0,.2) node [brcetxt, yshift=.5cm] {series};
\draw [brce] (e|-0,.2) -- (f|-0,.2) node [brcetxt, yshift=.5cm] {draw};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need the tickmarks, with possible node naming (not necessarily a b c d); and the braces.

Comment: @Hany see the updated answer.

Comment: Just one more request please. Can the increments between the nodes be controlled, for example making them 1.4cm or so.

Comment: @Hany if it is for adjusting the length/spacing, you can change ` \draw (\j,0) -- ++(1,0); `  to ` \draw (\j,0) -- ++(1.4,0);`.

Comment: Thank you. This controls the distance between the first node and beginning of line; not between the nodes.

Comment: @Hany my bad. change ` \draw (\j,0) -- ++(1,0); ` to ` \draw (\j*1.4,0) -- ++(1.4,0);`