# modifying calculated nodes in \foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

Using the following code from the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/463773/automating-setting-node-positions-in-foreach), how can the 0sigma node be replaced by `\mu` and how can the nodes 1sigma 2sigma 3sigma be replaced by +1sigma +2sigma +3sigma?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{pics/.cd,
curvea/.style n args={2}{code={
\node [red] at (#1,#2) (begin){}
([shift={(0.:.2cm)}]begin.center) node (beginr){}
([shift={(30:4.cm)}]beginr.center) node (midtop){}
([shift={(-30:4.cm)}]midtop.center) node (end){}
([shift={(0.:.2cm)}]end.center) node (endr){}
;
}}}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{mu +sigma}
\vspace {.6cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.86, transform shape]
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (8.4,0) node [black, xshift=.3cm, yshift=0cm] {Z};
\draw [thick,-latex](0,-2.) -- (8.4,-2.) node [black, xshift=.3cm, yshift=0cm] {Z};
\draw [thick,-latex](0,-2.5) -- (0,4);
\pic at (0,0) {curvea={.246}{.2}};
\draw[blue, very thick] ([shift={(-150.:.14cm)}]begin.center) to [out=10, in=10, looseness=.68] (beginr.center) to [out=10, in=180, looseness=.6] ([shift={(90:1.2cm)}]midtop.center) node (midtopnew){} to [out=0, in=170, looseness=.6] (end.center) to [out=170, in=170, looseness=.68] ([shift={(-30.:.14cm)}]endr.center) ([shift={(180:1.2cm)}]midtopnew.center) node (ml){} ([shift={(0:1.22cm)}]midtopnew.center) node (mr){};
\draw [very thick, black] (midtopnew.center) -- (midtopnew.center|-0,0);
\begin{scope}[xshift=-1.cm, yshift=-2.cm]
\foreach[count=\j] \i in {-3,...,3}
\draw[very thick] (\j*1.227,.2) -- ++(0,-.4) node[yshift=-.35cm]{\i$\sigma$}coordinate(\i);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to delve into the depths of `\pgfmathprintnumber`, you could just use some `\ifnum` statements.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{pics/.cd,
curvea/.style n args={2}{code={
\node [red] at (#1,#2) (begin){}
([shift={(0.:.2cm)}]begin.center) node (beginr){}
([shift={(30:4.cm)}]beginr.center) node (midtop){}
([shift={(-30:4.cm)}]midtop.center) node (end){}
([shift={(0.:.2cm)}]end.center) node (endr){}
;
}}}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{mu +sigma}
\vspace {.6cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.86, transform shape]
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (8.4,0) node [black, xshift=.3cm, yshift=0cm] {Z};
\draw [thick,-latex](0,-2.) -- (8.4,-2.) node [black, xshift=.3cm, yshift=0cm] {Z};
\draw [thick,-latex](0,-2.5) -- (0,4);
\pic at (0,0) {curvea={.246}{.2}};
\draw[blue, very thick] ([shift={(-150.:.14cm)}]begin.center) to [out=10, in=10, looseness=.68] (beginr.center) to [out=10, in=180, looseness=.6] ([shift={(90:1.2cm)}]midtop.center) node (midtopnew){} to [out=0, in=170, looseness=.6] (end.center) to [out=170, in=170, looseness=.68] ([shift={(-30.:.14cm)}]endr.center) ([shift={(180:1.2cm)}]midtopnew.center) node (ml){} ([shift={(0:1.22cm)}]midtopnew.center) node (mr){};
\draw [very thick, black] (midtopnew.center) -- (midtopnew.center|-0,0);
\begin{scope}[xshift=-1.cm, yshift=-2.cm]
\foreach[count=\j] \i in {-3,...,3}
{\ifnum\i=0
\draw[very thick] (\j*1.227,.2) -- ++(0,-.4) node[yshift=-.35cm]{$\mu$}coordinate(\i);
\else
\ifnum\i>0
\def\mysign{+}
\else
\def\mysign{}
\fi
\draw[very thick] (\j*1.227,.2) -- ++(0,-.4) node[yshift=-.35cm]{$\mysign\i\sigma$}coordinate(\i);
\fi
}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable answer.

Comment: @Hany As always, you're very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Just use the pgf key `\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/showpos}`
and display the number with `\pgfmathprintnumber{\i}` (see page 952 of the 3.0.1a manual).

#### Update:

To have a symbol \mu instead of the 0sigma, we can simply rewrite over the one that was written in the loop.

```
\draw (4*1.227,-.2)node[yshift=-.35cm,fill=white,minimum width=7mm]{$\mu$};
```

Foreach code:

```
 \begin{scope}[xshift=-1.cm, yshift=-2.cm]
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/showpos}
\foreach[count=\j] \i in {-3,...,3}
\draw[very thick] (\j*1.227,.2) -- ++(0,-.4) node[yshift=-.35cm]{\pgfmathprintnumber{\i}$\sigma$}coordinate(\i);
\draw (4*1.227,-.2)node[yshift=-.35cm,fill=white,minimum width=7mm]{$\mu$};
\end{scope}
```

[image: sigma plus]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{pics/.cd,
curvea/.style n args={2}{code={
\node [red] at (#1,#2) (begin){}
([shift={(0.:.2cm)}]begin.center) node (beginr){}
([shift={(30:4.cm)}]beginr.center) node (midtop){}
([shift={(-30:4.cm)}]midtop.center) node (end){}
([shift={(0.:.2cm)}]end.center) node (endr){}
;
}}}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{mu +sigma}
\vspace {.6cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.86, transform shape]
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (8.4,0) node [black, xshift=.3cm, yshift=0cm] {Z};
\draw [thick,-latex](0,-2.) -- (8.4,-2.) node [black, xshift=.3cm, yshift=0cm] {Z};
\draw [thick,-latex](0,-2.5) -- (0,4);
\pic at (0,0) {curvea={.246}{.2}};
\draw[blue, very thick] ([shift={(-150.:.14cm)}]begin.center) to [out=10, in=10, looseness=.68] (beginr.center) to [out=10, in=180, looseness=.6] ([shift={(90:1.2cm)}]midtop.center) node (midtopnew){} to [out=0, in=170, looseness=.6] (end.center) to [out=170, in=170, looseness=.68] ([shift={(-30.:.14cm)}]endr.center) ([shift={(180:1.2cm)}]midtopnew.center) node (ml){} ([shift={(0:1.22cm)}]midtopnew.center) node (mr){};
\draw [very thick, black] (midtopnew.center) -- (midtopnew.center|-0,0);
\begin{scope}[xshift=-1.cm, yshift=-2.cm]
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/showpos}
\foreach[count=\j] \i in {-3,...,3}
\draw[very thick] (\j*1.227,.2) -- ++(0,-.4) node[yshift=-.35cm]{\pgfmathprintnumber{\i}$\sigma$}coordinate(\i);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that the OP wants a `\mu` instead of `0\sigma`. This is why I used an `\ifnum` statement in my answer....