# Controlling space inside nodes in \foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

Using the following code from the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/463947/modifying-calculated-nodes-in-foreach-loop), how can I reduce the space between `\mu` and the `+`/`-` signs and  `\i`?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{che}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.86, transform shape]
\draw [thick](0,0) -- (9.,0);
\begin{scope}[xshift=-1.cm, yshift=0cm]
\foreach[count=\j] \i in {-4,...,4}
{\ifnum\i=0
\draw[very thick] (\j*1.134,.15) -- ++(0,-.3) node[yshift=-.4cm]{$\mu$}coordinate(\i);
\else
\ifnum\i>0
\def\plusign{+}
\else
\def\plusign{}
\fi
\draw[very thick] (\j*1.134,.2) -- ++(0,-.4) node[yshift=-.35cm]{\footnotesize$\mu\plusign\i\sigma$}coordinate(\i);
\fi}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `\scriptstyle` instead of `\footnotesize`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{che}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.86, transform shape]
\draw [thick](0,0) -- (9.,0);
\begin{scope}[xshift=-1.cm, yshift=0cm]
  \foreach[count=\j] \i in {-4,...,4}{
    \ifnum\i=0
      \draw[very thick] (\j*1.134,.15) -- ++(0,-.3) 
           node[yshift=-.4cm]{$\mu$}coordinate(\i);
    \else
      \ifnum\i>0
        \def\plusign{+}
      \else
        \def\plusign{}
      \fi
      \draw[very thick] (\j*1.134,.2) -- ++(0,-.4) 
           node[yshift=-.35cm]{$\scriptstyle\mu\plusign\i\sigma$}coordinate(\i);
      \fi
    }
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, with `\footnotesize`,

```
\footnotesize\medmuskip=0mu$\mu\plusign\i\sigma$
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just add negative spaces (and also make sure that they appear after the minus).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{che}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.86, transform shape]
\draw [thick](0,0) -- (9.,0);
\begin{scope}[xshift=-1.cm, yshift=0cm]
\foreach[count=\j] \i in {-4,...,4}
{\ifnum\i=0
\draw[very thick] (\j*1.134,.15) -- ++(0,-.3) 
node[yshift=-.4cm]{$\mu$}coordinate(\i);
\else
\ifnum\i>0
\def\plusign{\!+\!\i}
\else
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mi}{-\i}
\def\plusign{\!-\!\mi}
\fi
\draw[very thick] (\j*1.134,.2) -- ++(0,-.4) 
node[yshift=-.35cm]{\footnotesize$\mu\plusign\sigma$}coordinate(\i);
\fi}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]