# modifying decimal point in calculated nodes in \foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

Using the following code from the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/463947/modifying-calculated-nodes-in-foreach-loop)

How can the 0.10 ticks appear as 1.0

How can the x axis black ticks look like the red ones but keeping the intermediate ticks appearing empty

as in the lower drawing

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{beta}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.86, transform shape]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmnty}{.5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmntx}{.68}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\inc}{1}
\draw [thick,-](0,0) -- (7,0) node [pos=.5, yshift=-1.8cm] {p};
\draw [thick,-](0,0) -- (0,6) node [pos=.5, xshift=-1.4cm, rotate=90] {Beta};
\foreach \y [evaluate=\y as \aff using int(\y)]in {0,...,10}{
\draw [black, yshift=.6cm] (-.2,\incrmnty*\y) node [left] {0.\aff} -- +(0:.2);}

\foreach \x [evaluate= \x as \aff using int(\x)]in {0,...,10}{
\draw [black, xshift=.2cm] (\incrmntx*\x,0) -- +(-90:.2) node [below] {0.\aff};}

\foreach \x [evaluate= \x as \aff using int(\x)]in {0,2,...,10}{
\draw [red, xshift=.2cm, yshift=-.8cm] (\incrmntx*\x,0) -- +(-90:.2) node [below] {0.\aff};}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please include a MWE in your question. You don't even tell us which of the answers to the other question you are referring to.

Comment: I am sorry I just forgot it. I would like my code to look like the lower drawing. I tried 2 codes (giving me the upper drawing) but failed to accomplish that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xintfrac}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{beta}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.86, transform shape]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmnty}{.5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmntx}{.68}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\inc}{1}
\draw [thick,-](0,0) -- (7,0) node [pos=.5, yshift=-1.8cm] {p};
\draw [thick,-](0,0) -- (0,6) node [pos=.5, xshift=-1.4cm, rotate=90] {Beta};
\foreach \y [evaluate=\y as \aff using int(\y)]in {0,...,10}{
  \draw [black, yshift=.6cm] (-.2,\incrmnty*\y) node [left] 
  {\xintDecToString{\aff[-1]}} -- +(0:.2);
}

\foreach \x [evaluate= \x as \aff using int(\x)]in {0,...,10}{
  \draw [black, xshift=.2cm] (\incrmntx*\x,0) -- +(-90:.2) node [below]
   {\ifodd\aff\space\else\xintDecToString{\aff[-1]}\fi};
}


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is a little more complicated to get the `0.0` and not `0` (when using `xintfrac` which certainly is not the most natural way here, but a way I know ...)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xintfrac}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{beta}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.86, transform shape]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmnty}{.5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmntx}{.68}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\inc}{1}
\draw [thick,-](0,0) -- (7,0) node [pos=.5, yshift=-1.8cm] {p};
\draw [thick,-](0,0) -- (0,6) node [pos=.5, xshift=-1.4cm, rotate=90] {Beta};
\foreach \y [evaluate=\y as \aff using int(\y)]in {0,...,10}{
  \draw [black, yshift=.6cm] (-.2,\incrmnty*\y) node [left] 
  {\ifnum\aff=0 0.0\else\xintDecToString{\aff[-1]}\fi} -- +(0:.2);
}

\foreach \x [evaluate= \x as \aff using int(\x)]in {0,...,10}{
  \draw [black, xshift=.2cm] (\incrmntx*\x,0) -- +(-90:.2) node [below]
   {\ifodd\aff\space\else\ifnum\aff=0 0.0\else\xintDecToString{\aff[-1]}\fi\fi};
}


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am sorry for the delay of my response. Unfortunately, the computer in my workplace does not allow installing any program for security reason. Is there another way?

Comment: Please refer to my question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/466161/using-foreach-loop-for-negative-values-with-decimal-points